# Do Role/ClusterRole changes require the restart/replacement of the pods that are bound to those roles?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

For example, I change role verbs

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: provisioning-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

and run a Helm `upgrade`. Should the pods bound to those roles be restarted/replaced? (Those pods may be created manually without Helm.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to recreate the pods. When you create a Role/RoleBinding or ClusterRole/ClusterRoleBinding, the entities automatically get these permissions right away.

One prove used to be Helm itself. When you fresh install Helm, you get this error from Tiller saying has no access to the cluster to do anything, but then you give Tiller `cluster-role` (or any other with more caution) permissions and it starts working right away.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the `ServiceAccount` that your pod is using.

Let's say you are using the **default ServiceAccount** for your deployed pods. Then to give your pod additional access to resources, verbs, etc. you must bind the `ClusterRole` to that `ServiceAccount` through a `ClusterRoleBinding`.

If you have a `ServiceAccount` that is not currently binded to your pod, then you must do the `ClusterRoleBinding` and then load the `ServiceAccount` to the pod via the designed field `spec.serviceAccountName`. **Note** that you cannot update the `ServiceAccount` of an already created pod. You must restart it in this case.

Here is more detailed information: [enter link description here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)